# elastic search mapping error while loading data

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to create a single elastic search index using mapping but get the below error.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(['localhost'], verify_certs=True)
mapping = '''
{  
  "mappings":{  
    "logs_june":{  
      "_timestamp":{  
        "enabled":"true"
      },
      "properties":{  
        "logdate":{  
          "type":"date",
          "format":"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'''
#es.indices.delete(index='test-index') #delete indexes

es.indices.create(index='test-index', ignore=400, body=mapping)

doc={
  'logdate':'10/02/2016 11:22:22'
}
es.index(index='test-index',doc_type='test',body=doc)



    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'failed to parse [logdate]')
```

Error:

Caused by: MapperParsingException[failed to parse [logdate]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "10/02/2016 11:22:22" is malformed at "/02/2016 11:22:22"];
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:343)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseAndMergeUpdate(DocumentParser.java:765)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDynamicValue(DocumentParser.java:652)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseValue(DocumentParser.java:451)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:271)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseDocument(DocumentParser.java:131)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:304)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreate(IndexShard.java:500)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreateOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:481)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:214)

Comment: Please see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965270/elasticsearch-doesnt-allow-me-to-add-long-dict-transporterror400/45967524#45967524