# Elasticsearch doesn't allow me to add long dict [TransportError(400)]

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am using elasticsearch-py for adding some dict to the index in elastic,
I added dictionary to index and dictionary with lists in it, in my code was adding this dictionary but it give me the error like this:
   `RequestError: TransportError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'failed to parse [long_spec]')`
after search I got that I should add some maps in elastic and then I add `"long_spec":{ "type": "text" }` and in other test `"long_spec"{ "type": "string" }` in mapping but it doesn't work.

I use this in my python 
`self.es.index(index="new_index", doc_type='user',body=dict)`
and my dict is like this:

> `{'long_spec': [{'header': u'Design', 'specification': [{u'Device
>   type:': [u'Smart phone']}, {u'OS:': [u'Android (7.0)']}, {u'Form
>   factor:': [u'Candybar']}, {u'Dimensions:': [u'6.06 x 3.03 x 0.35
>   inches  (153.9 x 77 x 8.9 mm)']}, {u'Weight:': [u'6.38 oz  (181 g)']},
>   {u'Features:': [u'Fingerprint (touch), Touch sensitive control
>   keys']}, {u'Keys:': [u'Right: Volume control, Lock/Unlock key']},
>   {u'Colors:': [u'Black, Gold, Pink']}]}, {'header': u'Display',
>   'specification': [{u'Physical size:': [u'5.5 inches']},
>   {u'Resolution:': [u'720 x  1280 pixels']}, {u'\n': [u'267 ppi']},
>   {u'\n': [u'IPS LCD']}, {u'\n': [u'70.40 %']}, {u'Colors:': [u'16 777
>   216']}, {u'Touchscreen:': [u'Capacitive, Multi-touch', u'\n']},
>   {u'Features:': [u'Ambient light sensor, Proximity sensor']}]},
>   {'header': u'Camera', 'specification': [{u'Camera:': [u'13
>   megapixels', u'\n', u'LED', u'\n', u'F2.0', u'\n', u'25 mm', u'\n',
>   u'Dual-camera (13-megapixel, 120-degree viewing angle), Autofocus
>   (Phase detection)', u'\n', u'Touch to focus, Face detection,
>   Self-timer, Digital zoom, Geo tagging', u'\n', u'Exposure
>   compensation, ISO control, White balance presets', u'\n', u'Burst
>   mode, High Dynamic Range mode (HDR), Panorama', u'\n']},
>   {u'Camcorder:': [u'1920x1080 (1080p HD) (30 fps)', u'\n', u'Time-lapse
>   video, Picture-taking during video recording, Digital image
>   stabilization, Video calling, Video sharing', u'\n']}, {u'Front-facing
>   camera:': [u'8 megapixels', u'\n', u'Wide Angle, Flash', u'\n']}]},
>   {'header': u'Hardware', 'specification': [{u'\n': [u'Qualcomm
>   Snapdragon 430 8937 ']}, {u'\n': [u'Octa-core, 1400 MHz, ARM
>   Cortex-A53, 64-bit, 28 nm']}, {u'\n': [u'Adreno 505', u'\n']}, {u'\n':
>   [u'4 GB RAM (800 MHz) / LPDDR2']}, {u'\n': [u'64 GB']}, {u'\n':
>   [u'microSD, microSDHC, microSDXC up to 256 GB']}]}, {'header':
>   u'Battery', 'specification': [{u'\n': [u'5000 mAh']}, {u'Type:':
>   [u'Not user replaceable']}, {u'Fast Charge:': [u'Yes']}, {u'Talk time
>   (3G):': [u'40.00 hours']}, {u'Stand-by time (4G):': [u'46.0 days (1104
>   hours)']}, {u'Internet use:': [u'26 hours', u'\n']}, {u'Video
>   playback:': [u'22.00 hours']}]}, {'header': u'Multimedia',
>   'specification': [{u'Screen mirroring:': [u'Wireless screen share']},
>   {u'Music player:': [u'Album, Artist, Genre, Playlists', u'\n', u'Album
>   art cover, Background playback', u'\n', u'MP3, AAC, FLAC, WAV, M4A
>   (Apple lossless), AMR, OGG, MIDI', u'\n']}, {u'Video playback:':
>   [u'MPEG4, H.263, H.264', u'\n']}, {u'Radio:': [u'FM', u'\n']},
>   {u'Speakers:': [u'Earpiece, Loudspeaker']}, {u'Headphones connector:':
>   [u'3.5mm']}]}, {'header': u'Cellular', 'specification': [{u'GSM:':
>   [u'850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz']}, {u'UMTS:': [u'800, 850, 900,
>   1700/2100, 1900, 2100 MHz']}, {u'LTE (FDD):': [u'Bands 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
>   7, 8, 12, 17, 18, 19, 26, 28']}, {u'LTE (TDD):': [u'Bands 38, 41']},
>   {u'Data:': [u'LTE Cat 4 (150/50 Mbit/s), HSDPA+ (4G) 42.2 Mbit/s,
>   HSUPA 5.76 Mbit/s']}, {u'2G Data:': [u'EDGE, GPRS']}, {u'Nano SIM:':
>   [u'Yes']}, {u'Multiple SIM cards:': [u'2 slots']}, {u'VoLTE:':
>   [u'Yes']}, {u'Global Roaming:': [u'Yes']}]}, {'header': u'Phone
>   features', 'specification': [{u'Sensors:': [u'Accelerometer,
>   Gyroscope, Compass', u'\n']}, {u'Notifications:': [u'Haptic
>   feedback']}, {u'Phonebook:': [u'Unlimited entries, Caller groups,
>   Multiple numbers per contact, Search by both first and last name,
>   Picture ID, Ring ID']}, {u'Organizer:': [u'Calendar, Alarm,
>   Calculator, World clock, Timer, Stopwatch, Countdown timer']},
>   {u'Messaging:': [u'SMS, MMS, Threaded view, Predictive text input']},
>   {u'E-mail:': [u'IMAP, POP3, SMTP, Microsoft Exchange', u'\n']},
>   {u'Instant Messaging:': [u'Hangouts / Google Talk', u'\n']}, {u'Other
>   features:': [u'Voice dialing, Voice commands, Voice recording']}]},
>   {'header': u'Connectivity', 'specification': [{u'Bluetooth:': [u'4.1',
>   u'\n', u'Advanced Audio Distribution (A2DP), Audio/Visual Remote
>   Control Profile (AVRCP), Generic Access (GAP), Handsfree (HFP),
>   Headset (HSP), Message Access Profile (MAP), Object Push (OPP), Phone
>   Book Access (PBAP)', u'\n']}, {u'Wi-Fi:': [u'802.11 b, g, n', u'\n',
>   u'Yes', u'\n', u'Yes', u'\n']}, {u'USB:': [u'USB 2.0', u'\n',
>   u'microUSB', u'\n', u'Mass storage device, USB Host, USB charging',
>   u'\n']}, {u'Charging connector:': [u'microUSB']}, {u'\n': [u'GPS,
>   A-GPS, Glonass, BeiDou']}, {u'Navigation:': [u'Turn-by-turn
>   navigation, Voice navigation']}, {u'Other:': [u'VoIP, Tethering,
>   Computer sync, OTA sync']}]}, {'header': u'Availability',
>   'specification': [{u'Officially announced:': [u'17 Aug 2017']}]}]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get mapper_parsing_exception whenever the field you're trying to index is of different type than the mappings specified. In your case, the **long_spec** dictionary must have different data type across various documents and hence the error. You can replicate the error by following the below:

Try to index a document

```
PUT regexpindex/product/4
{ 
    "documentId": 1234,
    "someOtherInfo": "Product1\\Product1",
    "permissions": ["a", "b", "c", "g"]
}
```

Try to index another document with a string data type for documentId field

```
PUT regexpindex/product/4
{ 
    "documentId": "some-string",
    "someOtherInfo": "Product1\\Product1",
    "permissions": ["a", "b", "c", "g"]
}
```

and you'll get mapper_parsing_exception.

Please make sure that all your documents have the same data type across all the fields. You can also ignore the documents having different datatype if you think those documents are malformed. Read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html).

Comment: `"ignore_malformed": true` just work for data `"type": "integer"`, but my type is text and objects, anyway I've added that with integer type and test the new index and mapping and doesn't work again and give me `400, 'mapper_parsing_exception',`